# Computing Taylor Series of e^x with Haskell List Comprension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, taylor-series

I'm trying to do a haskell one-liner to compute the Taylor Series of e^x with this attempt:

```
-- 1 + x^1/1! + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + ...
expt x = [(x^e) / (product [1..n]) | e <- [0..], n <- [1..e]]
```

But I keep running into this issue:

```
<interactive>:5:1:
    No instance for (Integral t0) arising from a use of `expt'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Integral Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      instance Integral GHC.Types.Word -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
    In the expression: expt 2
    In an equation for `it': it = expt 2

<interactive>:5:6:
    No instance for (Num t0) arising from the literal `2'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the first argument of `expt', namely `2'
    In the expression: expt 2
    In an equation for `it': it = expt 2
```

I don't think I fully understand whats going wrong here - could someone explain it to me?

Comment: The generators `e <- [0..], n <- [1..e]` look wrong. Doesn't a single one suffice for the exp Taylor sum? As it is, the list comprehension will generate more terms than needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it with:

```
 expt x = [(x ** e) / (product [1..n]) | e <- [0..], n <- [1..e]]
```

The type of your function is `(Fractional t, Integral t) => t -> [t]`

The error indicates that it is ambiguous which type you want to use for `t`. There doesn't seem to actually be such a type. The reason for the `Integral` constraint is your use of `^`. If you replace it with `(**)` then the type of `expt` changes to

```
(Enum t, Floating t) => t -> [t]
```

and you can then use `Double` or `Float`.

Comment: `sum $ take 10 (expt 1.0)` ==> `5.875` --- The list comprehension of the OP is not the correct one

Answer (score 1):

The nth term of the Taylor series is x^n/n!, so the terms are computed by

```
expt x = [x**n / (product [1..n]) | n <- [0..]]
```

I have no idea what you were trying to do with the separate e and n variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
expt x = [(x^e) / (fromIntegral $ product [1..n]) | e <- [(0::Int)..], n <- [1..e]]
```

We've done two things:

1. Specified an explicit integral type for `e`
2. Converted the factorial (which is now an `Int`) into a `Fractional` instance with `fromIntegral`

You can still use any `Fractional` instance for `x` - e.g. `Float`, `Double`, etc.

Note: for 32-bit ints this will be good for about 12 terms.